# non-portable sign integer in c

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

The following is excerpted from [Writing solid code](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=uV0ZAQAAIAAJ&source=gbs_book_similarbooks), page 115.

> ```
> int strcmp( const char *strLeft, const char *strRight )
> {
>   for( NULL; *strLeft == *strRight; strLeft ++ ,strRight ++ )
>       if( strLeft == ‘\0’ ) 
>           return(0);
>   return ( (*strLeft<*strRight)?-1:1 );
> }
> ```
>
> **The moment you use <, or any other operator that use sign information**,
>   **you force the compiler to generate nonprtable code**

What does it(Bold line) mean? I know that

1. right shifting sign integer is non-portable.
2. comparing sign integer and unsigned integer is non-portable

Why is comparing two sign integer non-portable?

Comment: Comparing signed integers and unsigned integers does not constitute undefined or implementation-defined behavior and it can be done in safe and portable ways, but it's a bit tricky.

Comment: @Alex, what is the portable singed and unsigned integer comparison

Comment: For example: int SignedLessThanUnsigned(int s, unsigned u) { if (s < 0) return 1; else return s < u; } int SignedGreaterThanUnsigned(int s, unsigned u) { if (s < 0) return 0; else return s > u; } You get the idea.

Comment: Your own question makes more sense than the quoted text - compiler *output* is almost always severely non-portable.

Comment: `if( strLeft == ‘\0’ )` should have a * before strLeft.  (Also, the \0 is misquoted, ‘ should be ’, but presumably is ok in text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'char' type in C can be signed or unsigned. So here, if the strings are {0x81, 0} and {0x32, 0}, then if chars are signed 0x81 will be interpreted as a negative number (and the result will be that the first string compares less), and if chars are unsigned it'll be interpreted as a positive number (so the second string will compare less). This is non-portable in the sense that the results differ based on the compiler you've used.

Comment: And that's exactly what page 114 says, that it's only safe to use values between 0 and 127 for chars without risk making the code non-portable.

Comment: If that's the explanation, then I don't understand why the sentence says "force the compiler to generate". The code is portable once it has been generated, because signedness of the `char` type is implementation-defined.

Comment: So, The author wants to tell us that char could be interpreted as signed or unsigned, right?  so if I explicitly write function signiture as int strcmp( const signed char *strLeft, const signed char *strRight ), is it ok? In addition, does it still apply for c++?

Comment: @Complicatedseebio: Bad wording on author's part.

Comment: I agree CSB, the sentence is a bit careless.

Comment: @Chang Yes, using explicit signed or unsigned chars is often a good idea. Here it fixes the implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: @Chang: You should not redefine the existing functions, not under the same name, at least, especially if you're still including the relevant headers. In C++, char, signed char and unsigned char are also 3 distinct types and plain char can be either signed or unsigned. Just like in C.